# Create components library with TypeScript and Less files

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, webpack, bundle

I am building a React UI library with some components like Buttons, Inputs, textareas, etc., lets call it `mylib`. I will reuse it in many projects, like, for example, in `myApp`.  I will use TypeScript, so I will have to compile it to ES6. And it will use `.less` files for styling.

My question is regarding `.less` files. I don't know what is the correct approach with this: should I compile them in `myLib` or in `myApp`? Is it ok to use only TypeScript compiler, or is better to use also Webpack for any reason? I made an attempt, but I'm not sure if it's the right one.

My take on this is to compile TypeScript in `myLib`, but let `myApp` compile the `.less` files: I have the source code at `src` folder, and I compile it to a `dist` folder with TypeScript compiler. Then in the same script I copy the `.less` files from `src` to `dist` maintaining their relative paths using `cd src && find .  -name '*.less' -exec rsync -R {} ../dist ';'`.

This is the tree of `mylib` before compiling:

```
.
├── README.md
├── dist // destination folder
├── package.json
├── src
│   ├── components
│   │   └── MyComponent
│   │       ├── MyComponent.less
│   │       └── MyComponent.tsx
│   ├── css
│   │   ├── constants.less
│   │   ├── imports.less
│   │   └── reset.less
│   └── index.tsx
└── tsconfig.json
```

This is `MyComponent.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import './MyComponent.less';

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <div className="MyComponent">My component</div>;
    }
}

export default MyComponent;
```

This is `MyComponent.less`:

```
@c: .MyComponent;

@{c} {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: tomato;
}
```

The content of `tsconfig.json` is:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "esnext",
    "jsx": "react",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "dist"
  }
}
```

And the content of package.json is:

```
{
  "name": "@me/mycomponents",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "Components library",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc -d && cd src && find .  -name '*.less' -exec rsync -R {} ../dist ';' && cd .."
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^3.6.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.9.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.9.0",
  }
}
```

After compiling I get this:

```
.
├── README.md
├── dist
│   ├── components
│   │   └── MyComponent
│   │       ├── MyComponent.d.ts
│   │       ├── MyComponent.js
│   │       └── MyComponent.less
│   ├── css
│   │   ├── constants.less
│   │   ├── imports.less
│   │   └── reset.less
│   ├── index.d.ts
│   └── index.js
├── package.json
├── src
│   ├── components
│   │   └── MyComponent
│   │       ├── MyComponent.less
│   │       └── MyComponent.tsx
│   ├── css
│   │   ├── constants.less
│   │   ├── imports.less
│   │   └── reset.less
│   └── index.tsx
└── tsconfig.json
```

Then from `myApp` I should be able to import `MyComponent` and let `myApp` compile the `less` files.

Does this approach sounds correct you you?

Comment: What do you mean by correct? Does this approach *work* (e.g. have you tried implementing it)?

Comment: Well, it works. But I know its now a black/white, and there may be many approaches here for different reasons. I would like to know which one is better and why.

Comment: That sounds like a broad/opinion-based question that may be better suited for https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: May be. Or may be not if there is a flaw in my structure, and that is what this question is about.

Comment: If it works, then there's not a flaw. If you just want to know if it can be "better", then you enter into subjective territory, because "better" isn't well-defined in an objective way. If there are *specific* concerns you have with this approach, e.g. some scenario that this structure will simply not work, you can rephrase the question to ask about that. Otherwise, it's just asking for a general code review, which is one part too broad and one part opinion-based, and either should be on Software Engieering or even https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic.

Comment: «If it works, then there's not a flaw» Sorry, I disagree.

Answer (score 0):

> [less files:] should I compile them in myLib or in myApp?

- your component library should offer both the `.less` sourcecode and also the `.css` output
- `.css` is good for non-less consumers, so they can still utilize your styles
- `.less` is good for less-consumers who might use less-specific features like mixins or whatever

> Is it ok to use only TypeScript compiler, or is better to use also Webpack for any reason?

- yes, ideally your component library should only use the typescript compiler to generate the `dist/**/*.js` files
- leave bundling, minification, optimization, polyfilling, and those kinds of concerns up to the consuming applications
- you should also configure your `tsconfig.json` to generate `.d.ts` declaration files side-by-side with the javascript output (so that typescript consumers can benefit from typings/code-hints/auto-completion)

  - add `"declaration": true` to your `tsconfig.json
  - you might also like to add source maps for debugging with `"sourceMap": true`